# Enable Library Versioning by default for all new users Mysites

Tags: user-profile-service, custom-masterpage, versioning, mysites

One of our clients has asked us to set all Mysites with library versioning - have done this for all existing ones, but not so sure about the process to make it default for new Mysites generated automatically via sync service/timer job.

I've tried creating a new site collection (http://my/sites/hosttemplate) with a view to using CA > UPS SA > Setup My Sites to set it as the template, but when accessing the new site collection's Site Contents page there is no Documents library to apply versioning to.

I imagine this would need some editing of a master page/template package but unsure how to go about this.

They've not said so explictly, but I imagine if the URL for new sites had to change (it's currently http://my.client.com/personal/) this would prompt some whining so would prefer a way that preserves the URL creation as-is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 or 2016?

The my sites are not created on Sync. They are created when a user first visits the My Site Host (ordinarily). It also has nothing to do with the master page. Personal sites are always created under the managed path on the My Site Host. You have 3 options that don't involve changing the system files.

1. Write an event receiver and bind it to the Personal site template.
   Have it check for versioning and set the property as desired.
2. Run a scheduled PowerShell job to check for versioning and set it as
   necessary.
3. Pre-Provision the sites with PowerShell and set the properties. (Personally I don't like pre-provisioning personal sites.)

Comment: My mistake, I wasn't sure entirely of the process/terminology... option 2 sounds like the best bet to me tbh, looking for the least hassle option. Cheers!